# Will my personal number (shown on my Albanian passport or ID card) change when the document expires

Tags: paperwork, passport-renewals, albanian-citizens

I have to renew my Albanian passport.

As I understood, the new passport serial number will differ from the one in the old document.

But I'm wondering if the personal number changes too.

My logic says it doesn't, but does anyone know for sure?

Comment: You need to state your nationality. Passports vary significantly between countries.

Comment: @MJeffryes I'm from Albania. If I tell you my passport is a biometric one, isn't this information enough? Does the country matter?

Comment: @DonJoe: According to WikiPedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine-readable_passport), the personal number "may be used by the issuing country as it desires". So nationality will make a difference for this question. Out of curiosity, why would you like to know?

Comment: @mdd I live in another country, but I don't have their citizenship. In there I have different accounts (banc, university) based on my passport serial. Now that my passport is expiring, I will have to go and update my credentials. But next time, I'd like to give the PID, since I guess it mustn't change, and not the passport serial.

Comment: @mdd Including not using it at all.

Comment: If your passport serial number was 372044629, and you chose 372044629 as the password for your bank account, and your passport serial number changes to 983603849, then there is no need to change your bank account password. The old password 372044629 will stay working forever. PS. This is quite unsafe, because someone stealing your passport would have your banking password as well.

Comment: @gnasher729 I think the asker is worried that his bank won't accept his passport as ID since they think the right number is 372044629 but he's going to show up with passport number 983603849.

Answer (score 3):

In section 11 on the data page of the Albanian passport (nr. personal/personal no.) you will find your 'Numri i Identitetit' or abbreviated NID. It is a registration number assigned to you as a person by the Albanian authorities and not related to the passport per se. If you get a new passport, the NID will not change.

Comment: Would you kindly share also the link, since I was not able to find it?

Comment: @DonJoe A link to what? I don't even speak Albanian, but it took me perhaps two minutes to find what you are looking for on the English WIkipedia.

Comment: You just said `It is a registration number assigned to you as a person by the Albanian authorities and *not related to the passport per se*.` This is your opinion or you read it somewhere?

Comment: @DonJoe It is correct; many if not most European countries have the concept of a citizen's ID number, which is what the ALbanian NID is. It never changes unless you need to get protected identity, or renounce and re-acquire citizenship

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, in that case, please include a link to the actual Wikipedia page you found it. Those pages should include sources and/or links which link to authorative sites.

Answer (score 1):

The passport number is individual to each passport; the [citizen ID number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number) is individual to each citizen, and never changes under normal circumstances.

SO the passport number will be different, but your citizen ID number the same

Answer (score -1):

Since I can't find an official answer for my nationality, from [wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number#Albania) and from the majority of the other countries, being that the personal number is calculated using some formulae, I take that **it does not change** when renewing the passport.